# Html Dropdownlist Binding in mvc3

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, jquery, html-select

i need to bind the @html.dropdownlist() using another dropdownlist .

For example: ddl1: Letters and numbers.

1. when i select the letters in ddl1 bind the letters like a,b,c,d in ddl2
2. when i select the numbers in ddl1 bind the numbers like 1,2,3,4 in ddl2

in default page loading

dd1: select the case and dd2: select the dd1

using mvc3 format

Answer (score 1):

I think you need jquery to do that.

```
$("#Dropdown1").change(function () {
            var value= $("#Dropdown").val();
            if(value=="Letters")
        {
        populatedropdown(listofletters);
        }
       else if(value=="Numbers")
        {
        populatedropdown(listofnumbers);
        }
        });


 function populatecities(list) {
        $("#dropdown2").html('');
        $.each(list, function (id, option) {
            select.append($('<option></option>').val(id).html(option));
        });
    }
```

I think this will do it...